# Spring nested transactions not working with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, spring, jooq

I want to manage my transactions with Spring `@Transactional` and support nested transaction by following [this example](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/tree/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example) in order to do so.

My problem is if I call `UserService.addAdmin()` that `SpringTransactionProvider.begin()` and `SpringTransactionProvider.commit()` are not getting called for some reason which indicates that it is not working the way I'm doing it ..

I'm having my [service](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example/src/main/java/org/jooq/example/spring/impl/DefaultBookService.java) implemented:

```
/*
 *
 */
public class UserService {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(UserService.class.getName());

    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    public UserService(DSLContext ctx) {        
        this.adminRepository = new AdminRepository(ctx);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addAdmin(String userId) {
        DSLContext ctx = adminRepository.getCtx();
        ctx.insertInto(Admin.ADMIN)
            .set(Admin.ADMIN.USER_NAME, userId)
            .execute();
    }
}
```

As well as defined my [configuration file](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example/src/main/resources/jooq-spring.xml) **servlet-context.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mz_db" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="huehuehue" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure Spring's transaction manager to use a DataSource -->
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure jOOQ's TransactionProvider as a proxy to Spring's transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionProvider"
    class="com.mz.server.web.SpringTransactionProvider">
</bean>

<!-- Configure jOOQ's ConnectionProvider to use Spring's TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy,
     which can dynamically discover the transaction context -->
<bean id="transactionAwareDataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DataSourceConnectionProvider" name="connectionProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="transactionAwareDataSource" />
</bean>

<!-- Configure the DSL object, optionally overriding jOOQ Exceptions with Spring Exceptions -->
<bean id="dsl" class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext">
    <constructor-arg ref="config" />
</bean>

<!-- Invoking an internal, package-private constructor for the example
     Implement your own Configuration for more reliable behaviour -->
<bean class="org.jooq.impl.DefaultConfiguration" name="config">
    <property name="SQLDialect"><value type="org.jooq.SQLDialect">POSTGRES_9_4</value></property>
    <property name="connectionProvider" ref="connectionProvider" />
    <property name="transactionProvider" ref="transactionProvider" />
</bean>

<!-- BEGIN Services -->

<bean id="userService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.UserService">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="dsl" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and basically a copy of [`SpringTransactionProvider`](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/blob/master/jOOQ-examples/jOOQ-spring-example/src/main/java/org/jooq/example/spring/SpringTransactionProvider.java):

```
public class SpringTransactionProvider implements TransactionProvider {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SpringTransactionProvider.class);

    @Autowired
    DataSourceTransactionManager txMgr;

    public SpringTransactionProvider() {
        LOGGER.info("Ctor()");
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(TransactionContext ctx) {
        LOGGER.info("##### begin #####");
        TransactionStatus tx = txMgr.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_NESTED));
        ctx.transaction(new SpringTransaction(tx));
    }

    @Override
    public void commit(TransactionContext ctx) {
        LOGGER.info("##### commit #####");
        txMgr.commit(((SpringTransaction) ctx.transaction()).tx);
    }

    @Override
    public void rollback(TransactionContext ctx) {
        LOGGER.info("##### rollback #####");        
        txMgr.rollback(((SpringTransaction) ctx.transaction()).tx);
    }
}
```

I would have expected to see

```
INFO  com.mz.server.web.SpringTransactionProvider  - Ctor()
DEBUG com.mz.server.web.servlet.UserServletImpl    - Login request by userId: username
INFO  com.mz.server.web.SpringTransactionProvider  - #### begin ####
INFO  com.mz.server.web.service.UserService        - Yay!
INFO  com.mz.server.web.SpringTransactionProvider  - #### commit ####
```

but I'm only getting

```
INFO  com.mz.server.web.SpringTransactionProvider  - Ctor()
DEBUG com.mz.server.web.servlet.UserServletImpl    - Login request by userId: username
INFO  com.mz.server.web.service.UserService        - Yay!
```

Why does the `SpringTrancationProvider` not getting utilized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ's [`TransactionProvider`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/TransactionProvider.html) provides an implementation for the explicit [jOOQ transaction API](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/), wiring it to Spring, which you don't seem to be using. An example `addAdmin()` method that uses the explicit jOOQ transaction API would be this one:

```
// no @Transactional - no need for declarative transaction management
public void addAdmin(String userId) {
    adminRepository.getCtx().transaction(configuration -> {
        DSL.using(configuration)
           .insertInto(Admin.ADMIN)
           .set(Admin.ADMIN.USER_NAME, userId)
           .execute();
    });
}
```

The `TransactionProvider` is not involved if you use Spring's declarative `@Transaction` API. In other words, you don't need it.

Comment: Ah okay, I see! The reason why I wanted to use `@Transactional` is that e.g. in Hibernate using Spring you don't have a session without it. Having no session would throw an exception. If I execute an `INSERT` statement in jOOQ **without** `@Transactional` and throw an exception, the record gets persisted (no rollback). But **with** `@Transactional` a rollback is performed. I'm not quite sure why this is the case.

Comment: So the main question is: Can I use Springs Declarative Annotations with jOOQ and have nested transactions the way I am doing it?  I would prefer to use Declarative Transactions over using `DSLContext.transaction()` in order to have internal savepoints and rollbacks if that's somehow possible.

Comment: Yes, you can use Spring's declarative transactions without any issues. jOOQ is just type safe JDBC, so wherever you would write a JDBC statement, you can write a jOOQ statement. Nothing in jOOQ will get in the way of that. Just provide jOOQ with any `DataSource` from Spring and you're set. I suspect there is simply some confusion around what the point of jOOQ's `TransactionProvider` is...

Comment: Okay I see! I think I also got the wrong understanding on how Spring works with nested transaction. It's hard to learn three big frameworks at once.. I can tell.. But thanks as always for your help! :)

Comment: I agree. I've learned a lot but I started with GWT, Hibernate and Spring. Each framework has its own quite flat learning curve imho ^^ and now that I got things working I stepped away from Hibernate due to things I was reading in blogs and now I'm transitioning to jOOQ which means I'll have to learn another framework. But I'm not complaining :D it's just a lot of work that kills a lot of free-time. But like you said, it's a good investment :)