# How to properly set up transaction management for jOOQ in Spring Boot in the presence of JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

Let's start with a small integration test:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@Transactional(isolation = READ_UNCOMMITTED)
class JooqConfigIT) {
    companion object {
        const val testProjectId = 2021520
    }

    @Autowired
    lateinit var ctx: DSLContext

    @Test
    fun `dialect is set to postgres`() {
        assertThat(ctx.configuration().dialect()).isEqualTo(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    }

    @RepeatedTest(2, name = LONG_DISPLAY_NAME)
    fun `A - if jOOQ does not respect Spring transactions, either A or B should fail`() {
        ctx.insertInto(PROJECT)
            .columns(PROJECT.ID, PROJECT.NAME)
            .values(testProjectId, "Hakuna")
            .execute()
    }

    @RepeatedTest(2, name = LONG_DISPLAY_NAME)
    fun `B- if Spring does not respect jOOQ transactions, either A or B should fail`() {
        ctx.transaction { config ->
            DSL.using(config)
                .insertInto(PROJECT)
                .columns(PROJECT.ID, PROJECT.NAME)
                .values(testProjectId, "Matata")
                .execute()
        }
    }
}
```

Premise is simple:

- there will be a transaction at the start of each `@Test` that will be rolled back at the end of the test, so
- if jOOQ is integrated correctly, there will be no exception because `testProjectId` will not be in the database by the end of either test. on the other hand,
- if it's not set up correctly, at least one of `A` or `B` will write it into the database and at least one of the repetitions will fail because it's using the same ID
- the reason we're duplicating both `A` and `B` is that if either direction IS set up correctly and the other isn't
  (e.g. Spring is aware of jOOQ transactions but jOOQ is not aware of Spring transactions), we still can never run into the case where we commit the transaction at the end of all tests (and therefore don't catch the error) because after writing to the DB, there's still a second test that tries to do the same thing and will fail

So we know what we want, but how do we get there

There are multiple resources on the web telling you how to achieve that, let me save you the googling and just mention it here:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class JooqConfig(
    private val dataSource: DataSource,
    private val transactionManager: DataSourceTransactionManager,
) {

    /** Makes jOOQ respect Spring transactions (e.g. [Transactional] annotations)*/
    @Bean
    fun dataSourceConnectionProvider() = DataSourceConnectionProvider(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource))

    /** Makes Spring respect jOOQ transactions (i.e. `ctx.transaction{config -> ...}`)*/
    @Bean
    fun springTransactionProvider(): TransactionProvider = SpringTransactionProvider(transactionManager)

    private class SpringTransactionProvider(private val transactionManager: DataSourceTransactionManager) : TransactionProvider {
        companion object {
            private val log: JooqLogger = JooqLogger.getLogger(SpringTransactionProvider::class.java)
        }

        override fun begin(ctx: TransactionContext) {
            log.info("begin transaction")
            val transactionDefinition = DefaultTransactionDefinition(PROPAGATION_NESTED)
            val transactionStatus = transactionManager.getTransaction(transactionDefinition)
            ctx.transaction(SpringTransaction(transactionStatus))
        }

        override fun commit(ctx: TransactionContext) {
            log.info("commit transaction");
            transactionManager.commit(ctx.transactionStatus)
        }

        override fun rollback(ctx: TransactionContext) {
            log.info("rollback transaction");
            transactionManager.rollback(ctx.transactionStatus)
        }

        private class SpringTransaction(val status: TransactionStatus) : Transaction

        private val TransactionContext.transactionStatus
            get() = when (val tx = this.transaction()) {
                is SpringTransaction -> tx.status
                else -> throw IllegalStateException("Expected SpringTransaction but was $tx")
            }
    }
}
```

What I *haven't* yet found, though, is a mention anywhere that Spring Boot already does exactly that in `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration`:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
@ConditionalOnClass(DSLContext.class)
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@AutoConfigureAfter({ DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, TransactionAutoConfiguration.class })
public class JooqAutoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionProvider.class)
    public DataSourceConnectionProvider dataSourceConnectionProvider(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceConnectionProvider(new TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(dataSource));
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)
    public SpringTransactionProvider transactionProvider(PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
        return new SpringTransactionProvider(txManager);
    }

    //...

}
```

So none of this is necessary, EXCEPT if you're one of the lucky people like me who happen to also have JPA in the app because you're thinking about migrating to jOOQ. (Or in my case, really eager to eventually get rid of JPA), in which case `B` may fail for you, but not because Spring isn't aware of the transactions, but rather because

```
JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities
org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities
org.springframework.transaction.NestedTransactionNotSupportedException: JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.getSavepointManager(JpaTransactionManager.java:762)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.createSavepoint(JpaTransactionManager.java:741)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractTransactionStatus.createAndHoldSavepoint(AbstractTransactionStatus.java:140)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.handleExistingTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:457)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:352)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.SpringTransactionProvider.begin(SpringTransactionProvider.java:48)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.lambda$transactionResult0$0(DefaultDSLContext.java:537)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools$35$1.block(Tools.java:5246)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3128)
    at org.jooq.impl.Tools$35.get(Tools.java:5243)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transactionResult0(DefaultDSLContext.java:595)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transactionResult(DefaultDSLContext.java:512)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDSLContext.transaction(DefaultDSLContext.java:612)
    at my.app.config.JooqConfigIT.B- if Spring does not respect jOOQ transactions, either A or B should fail(JooqConfigIT.kt:36)
    at ...
```

We learn three things from this

- JPA sucks - but I already knew that when I started dabbling with jOOQ
- even if you put in your own `JooqConfig` that defines this nice `springTransactionProvider` bean, Spring ignores it and instead uses its own (as evident from the stacktrace)
- I really don't care about nested transactions as I'm going to create my own `@Repository` classes anyway that will be neatly hidden behind an `@Transactional`-annotated service so all the transaction management will already be taken care of by Spring.

I *could* just push the `@Transactional` annotation from the class to the `A` test method, implement a manual rollback (exception) in `B` and call it a day.

OR, we could take the time to try to come up with a proper configuration.

My idea was to just define my own `springTransactionProvider`, change the `TransactionDefinition` to `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` s.t. jOOQ does not try to create a nested transaction and hope that fixes things.

But the fact that my bean does not show up in the stacktrace at all makes me think this is not the way to go and there should be a different way.

So how do I make this work?

Comment: Is your configuration actually being picked up? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893121/spring-nested-transactions-not-working-with-jooq .

Comment: @M.Deinum The config may be picked up, but its beans are not, as mentioned in the issue. :) As you can see from the stacktrace: "at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.SpringTransactionProvider". (I also changed mine to `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` to test it).

Comment: Which is why I removed my comment and mentioned if your config is actually even being picked up (it doesn't appear so). But, judging on the linked question, you shouldn't need all that configuration (and you might only need your own customized `SpringTransactionProvider` which I would just extend not reimplement. \